# meaning of 'positive' in 'trapped in a positive self-reinforcing cycle'

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of *positive* in the following text, please?

> The causes for the decrease in the quality of life [in mega-cities]
>   are paradoxically the prosperity endowed on such metropolitan centers.
>   Their growth is largely due to the increase of opportunities on offer
>   which in turn increases their attractiveness; essentially they are
>   trapped in a **positive** self-reinforcing cycle.

I looked it up in dictionaries:

- composed of or possessing actual or specific qualities; real ⇒ a positive benefit  (Collins American Dictionary)
- arbitrarily or formally laid down or imposed :  prescribed by express enactment  ⇒  (MW Unabridged Dictionary) ; [In this sense it seems to me that the writer means *metropolises are forced into such cycles* [?]]

, but am not sure of either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here **positive** means **self-reinforcing**; and hence is redundant in the sentence you quote.  The sentence would be clearer with **positive** deleted.

Where does this particular meaning of **positive** come from?  It alludes to the idea of 'positive feedback'.  This phenomenon has a wide range of concrete and figurative usages in English, as evidenced in its [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_feedback) entry.